# how to create a functionality toview other users profile in a social network

Tags: php, mysql

```
 <?php
  $post_query="SELECT firstname,lastname,postupdate,time,profilepics FROM logindetails AS ld INNER JOIN postdetails AS pd ON ld.email=pd.email INNER join profilepictures AS pp ON ld.email=pp.email ORDER BY time DESC";
  $result_query=mysql_query($post_query);
  $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result_query);

    while( $query_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result_query))
    {
        echo'<div class="panel">';
        echo'<div class="panel-heading">';
        echo'<img src="'.$query_row["profilepics"].'" height="50px" width="50px" class="img-circle"/>'." ".'<strong>'.$query_row["firstname"]." ".$query_row["lastname"].'</strong>';
        echo'<hr />';
        echo'</div>';
        echo'<div class="panel-body" id="post_background">';
    echo $query_row["postupdate"];
    echo"<br />";
        echo $query_row["time"];
    echo'</div>';
    echo'<hr />';
    echo'<a href="#" id="like"><p style="padding-left:20px; font-size:20px;"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Like"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> like </p> </a>';
    echo'</div>';
    }
      ?>
```

I am creating a kind of social network, I want to create a feature to view other users profile by clicking over their name , How can I grab the Id of the user that is being clicked and display their details on a different page for viewing their profile...so  Can I do implement this using php.

This is just a prototype of post feature all I want to do is as as user clicks on the name of the user `$query_row["firstname"]." ".$query_row["lastname"]` ... The user must get redirect to the particular person profile...

Comment: *Step 1.* Immediately stop using `mysql_query` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php Use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead...

Comment: *Step 2.* in your href create a custom link such as `href="?id=$query_row['id']"` and then you can do a search on whatever page you send them to based on that id.

Comment: how we can reference their account, suppose two users having the same name so ho we can pull correct data from DB How to take the person Id corresponding to its name..please help me with the sample code...

Comment: @hatim don't do it by username, either do it by a unique reference (ie: nickname) or by the primary key value.

Comment: The simplest approach is to add an id column with an autoincrement and then you can reference a user with this. The alternative is to use another unique field already in your database.

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone I have done all the database connectivity...But I am not able to implement the link part..can please provide me with the code snippet..